# IntelliJ IDEA updating classes takes too much time

Tags: intellij-idea

I really like IDEA, but when I work with a webapp running on Tomcat and I modify only a single java class file, I have to do an update classes and resources and it takes much more time to do it than in eclipse. In eclipse it's instant, at least I don't notice anything, in IDEA it does a make and updates caches and I don't know what else but it's really annoying. 
Why is that and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Update would depend on your project and its configuration in IDEA. Normally it should not take too long as only the required steps are performed. Compilation is incremental and would be instant. In order to understand why it takes long for your project, we'll need the sample project and the exact steps to reproduce it, please file an issue to our [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

If you want really fast updates, you may consider using [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/), it has [plug-in for IDEA](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4441).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm amazed IntelliJ support tracks SO and answers almost immediately :) Could it be the reason if it's a Spring Roo project and I use ajc?

Comment: Yes, ajc is known to be slow when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Not so with IntelliJ 10.x.  Updates don't require a complete build and redeployment.  Try the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can actually check your Project Settings. There in the modules section you can mark some of your unnecessary folders as excluded.

This might speed up your process as the unnecessary files are now not been indexed.

Comment: The number of files to be indexed has nothing to do with the time needed to update generated files.